WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage
I have deployed Alma Linux 9 and MariaDB 10.11.7 with Galera 4 on two AWS instances and all the ports and firewall rules are open between 2 instances, I set the proper wsrep options and I am still seeing the issue below.
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage: exit codes: 124 0
By the way , I have tried the same setup in my local laptop, it worked and SST happens and I am able to form the cluster. I see issues when deployed in cloud instances.. Can you please assist? I have been debugging this issue since a month.

Is there already data in the data directory? If so, is there a lot? Or is this a completely new instance? Are there any warnings or errors in the donor's log files? Do you see the expected processes starting on the donor? And on the receiver? Are you using IPv6? Is socat installed on both donor and receiver? Have you read this page? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-sst-method/

We found the issue.
If we install mariadb.org repo on Alma Linux 9 the HA is broken with the following error:
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage: exit codes: 124 0
After spending a while we tried installing mariadb from RHEL stream repo & tried HA which is working as intended.
